# formula to add three columns automatically when new row is added

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, lambda, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to automatically add a formula in Google sheets when row is added. The formula is an output of adding (sum) three columns.

Here is my formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(F:F)=1, "Count", IF(ISBLANK(F:F), "", SUM(F2:H2))))
```

The above formula populates the sum of SUM(F2:H2) in all the rows

If I use this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(F:F)=1, "Count", IF(ISBLANK(F:F), "", SUM(F:H))))
```

Then the output is the total sum of column F, G, H

Comment: *Can someone please help?* is not an acceptable question here. Please ask a **specific** question.

Comment: You have a Google Sheets tag. The tagging system works extremely well here without help. There's no point in redundantly repeating tag information in the title. Please do not roll back edits made by users who are considerably more experienced with the site. Repeating the tag information in the title is simply noise that isn't needed. Also, personal attacks or insults are a violation of the site's Code of Conduct. Please conduct yourself with that in mind.

Comment: See [Who are the staff, and what is their role here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/staff)

Comment: Moderation is done by users with sufficient reputation, in which I am included. Diamond moderators are the admins. I'd suggest you go back to the [help] and actually read the pages to improve your understanding of how the site works. It will greatly improve your experiences here.

Comment: Regardings tags see https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BYROW to have the sums of each row. Put this in Row 1 of your column

```
={"Count";BYROW(F2:H,LAMBDA(each,IF(COUNTA(each)=0,"",SUM(each))))}
```